# Eliminar espacio en cadena en java

Tags: java, java-8

Amigos estoy desarrollando un proyecto en java en el que se tiene que pasar por parámetros por consola unos comando ejemplo de lo que se tiene que pasar seria `metodo[-d parametro]` asi tal cual se tiene que escribir por consola de java, bien ahora pasa lo siguiente, el comando `-d` puede variar en base al metodo a ejecutar o la funcionalidad que se requiera, la logro detectar si se pasa una d o cualquier parámetro mediante `indexOf`, ahora el problema que tengo es que `parametro` es opcional, puede ir como no, y no e podido saber si se pasa o no

Verán esto es lo que tengo:

```
private static String[] analizarComandos(String cmd){

    int comando = cmd.indexOf("d");

    String parametro = cmd.substring(comando+1, (cmd.length()-1));

    parametro = parametro.trim();

    parametro = parametro.replaceAll("\\s", "+");

    System.out.println("Parametro =>" + parametro);

    String[] resul = {cmd.substring(comando-1, comando+1), parametro};

    return resul;
}
```

Lo que estoy tratando de optener es un espacio en blanco para poder eliminar y asi saber si se paso o no, pero no me funciona el resultado, veran al imprimir lo que me genera es lo siguiente:

```
Parametro =>
0==> d
1==> 
Detecta algo
```

Este es lo que me imprime y asi es como lo mando a imprimir:

```
String[] d = analizarComandos(comando);

System.out.println("0==> " + d[0]);

System.out.println("1==> " + d[1]);

if(d[1].equals(" ")){

   System.out.println("No tiene nada");

}else{

   System.out.println("Detecta algo");

}
```

Como ven aqui trato de comparar si en la posición 1 donde se va el parámetro esta un espacio en blanco o que.

Como puedo saber o detectar si me pasan o no un parámetro

Comment: cuando se pasan parametros por linea de comandos java los separa por espacios (como un `String.split(" ")`) en una arreglo de String (el famoso `args[]`). Cuando hace `metodo [-d parametro]` la parte final queda en el arreglo args[] así args[0] = "-d" y args[1] = "parametro"  de ahí lo único que debe hacer es validar si el tamaño del arreglo args es cero entonces no hay parametros y si es uno entonces falta el parametro y si es dos se valida que args[0] inicie por el caracter '-'... Es mi idea, espero le ayude en su solución.

Comment: Amigo si muy interesante la idea, pero estamos usando un menu por consola, es decir hemos creado un menu tipo 1) metodo [-d parametro] 2metodo [-d parametro] 3)metodo [-d parametro] escriba el comando: algo es el menu, aun que se tenga eso, esa forma podria funcionar?

Comment: Pues a la final es hacer un split por espacio al comando ( metodo [-d parametro ] ) y validar la longitud del arreglo resultante de acuerdo (longitud uno = método sin parametro, longitud 2 = comando mal formado, longitod 3 = se envia parametro)

Comment: Acabo de probar y no me devuelve siempre 0 el args

Comment: Sip, porque ustedes crearon un menu, y no lo envian desde la ejecucion de programa. El args[] solo se crea en la ejecución del programa y su ambito es el método main del programa.

Comment: @isaac Entiendo si claro esta opción es mas viable, de echo es la mejor por decir, por que el tamaño me dira todo lo necesario, gracias amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo asi

```
private static String[] analizarComandos(String cmd){
  String[] args = cmd.split(" ");
  if(args.length == 2 || args.length == 0){
    System.out.println("error en comando.")
  }else if(args.length == 1){
    //haga lo que deba hacer sin parametro ya que solo va el método
  }else if(args.length == 3){
    if("-d".equals(args[2])){
      //haga lo que deba hacer con parametro -d
    }else{
     //haga lo que deba hacer si no es -d
    }
  }
  //demas código que requiera
}
```

Comment: "-d".equals(args[2]) esta operacion no me la reconoce no me reconoce el signo -

Comment: simule un paso de cadena con -d y funciono de forma correcta, usted pudo solucionarlo???